# How can I transform a vector containing semicolon delimited lists into a presence/absence matrix?

Tags: r

I have a vector and each element of the vector contains a string which is comprised of a semicolon and/or comma delimited list of attributes.  What I want to do is take that vector and turn it into a presence/absence matrix for each of the attributes in the list.

The approach I have taken so far is to first grab all the semi-colon delimited elements in the vector as follows:

```
OrientationList <- c(NULL)
for (i in levels(stroller_attributes$Orientation))
{ OrientationList <- paste(OrientationList, ",", i)}

OrientationList <- unique(gsub("^[[:space:]]|[[:space:]]$", "", unlist(strsplit(OrientationList, split=";|,"))))
```

This gives me a list of all of the attributes that are contained within the vector.  But now what I want to do is create a new matrix that has length(OrientationList) columns and rows(stroller_attributes) rows, which I do as

```
OrientationFactorsMatrix <- matrix(ncol=length(OrientationList), nrow=nrow(stroller_attributes))
colnames(OrientationFactorsMatrix) <- OrientationList
```

Next I need to proceed through that original vector, stroller_attributes$Orientation and identify which elements are contained within each element, and then indicate the presence or absence for this element in the OrientationFactorsMatrix with a TRUE or FALSE value.  My initial instinct was to do something like

OrientationList %in% stroller_attributes$Orientation[16] which would automatically generate the presence/absence values for each element in the matrix (Hooray!), unfortunately because if the element contains two different items in a comma/semicolon delimited list, it returns FALSE.  In essence, I want to do that %in% check, but do a "does this contain the term" rather than "does it only contain exactly this term".

I'd appreciate any help.
Brad

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 21L, 21L, 23L, 22L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 24L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 19L, 12L, 
17L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 17L, 21L, 17L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 25L, 
13L, 2L, 25L, 1L, 26L, 2L, 25L, 25L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 2L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 13L, 21L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 
10L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 
2L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 2L, 8L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 15L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 15L, 14L, 
8L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 24L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Forward Facing", 
"Forward Facing ", "Forward Facing, Parent Facing", "Forward Facing; Full lie flat", 
"Forward Facing; Infant Car Seat", "Forward facing; Lie flat", 
"Forward Facing; Lie Flat", "Forward Facing; Lie flat option for Infants", 
"Forward Facing; Lie Flat; 2 Children Forward-Facing; 2 Children 1x Forward Facing, 1x Lie Flat; 2 Children 1x Forward Facing, 1x Parent Facing (Infant Car Seat); 1x Parent Facing (Infant Car Seat)", 
"Forward Facing; Lie-Flat Configuration For Newborns", "Forward Facing; Parent Facing", 
"Forward Facing; Parent Facing; Lie Flat", "Forward Facing; Parent Facing; Lie Flat On Buggy; Lie Flat Off Buggy", 
"Forward Facing; Parent Facing; Recline", "Forward Facing; Rear Facing; Lie Flat", 
"Lie Flat; Forward Facing", "Lie Flat; Forward Facing; Parent Facing", 
"Lie Flat; Forward Facing; Travel System", "Lie Flat; Forward-Facing", 
"Lie Flat; Parent Facing; Forward Facing", "Lie Flat; Travel System; Forward Facing; Second Seat", 
"Lie Flat; Travel System; Forward Facing; Second Seat; Parent Facing", 
"Off Stroller Bassinet; Forward Facing; Parent Facing; Lie Flat", 
"Reversible Seat", "Travel System; Forward Facing; Second Seat; Parent Facing"
), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Please provide `stroller_attributes` or people will downvote your post. Use `dput()`

Comment: I can do that, but I don't understand how the details of the stroller_attributes changes anything.  I'm asking a process question.
That said, thanks for the input and the dput suggestion. I wasn't trying to criticize you if it came off that way, just trying to understand why people would down vote the post in this particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as is often the case, writing out the question in a detailed way helped me figure out the answer to my own question.  Here is the solution

```
for (i in 1:nrow(stroller_attributes))
{
result <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", tolower(OrientationList)) %in% tolower(gsub("[[:space:]]", "", unlist(strsplit(as.character(stroller_attributes$Orientation[i]), split=",|;"))))
OrientationFactorsMatrix[i, ] <- result
}
```

The key part of it is that I have to take the comma/semicolon separated list in the original vector and turn it into a vector of items with enlist. Then I go and clean it up by removing all white space, and convert it to lower case.  I do the same basic operation to the contents of OrientationList, and then the %in% operator creates the output that I want.